# Heisenberg uncertainty principle - question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

> *A beam of particles each having mass $m$ and velocity $v$ in the incident on a circular hole of radius $b$ located on a screen. If another screen is placed at a distance $D$ from the hole, determine the minimum size of the pattern formed on the screen by the beam.*

Answer (score 1):

Velocity component in transverse direction $v_{\perp}>\frac{\hbar }{m b}$. Time to reach second screen from first $t=\frac{D }{v}$ 
$$R=v_{\perp} t>\frac{\hbar }{m b}\frac{D }{v}$$.